# How to prevent double / duplicate form submissions in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I discovered the Security Component in CakePHP helps to prevent CSRF by adding tokens as hidden values to forms.

What I was wondering is if there was anyway to prevent duplicate form submissions using this Component or some other component/helper?

In previous projects, I used a unique hash saved in a session, which is read then deleted upon submit. A repeated submit would have that same hash and an error would be produced.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've puted onClick event that disables the button like this:

```
<?= $this->Form->button('Salvar', [
                    'value' =>'Submit', 
                    'onClick' => 'form.submit();this.disabled=true'
]) 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement the same type of thing in Cake as you've done before.

On submit, set a session variable that marks that form as having been submitted.  Make sure to put an expiry time after it (within a few seconds should do the trick).  If the session variable is there when you process the form (and you're within that expiration time), then you've got a resubmit, so don't save the form data.

I'd recommend doing this within the save(..) method of your model, so you don't need to worry about adding it in multiple code locations.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but don't think you should be accessing SessionComponent from the model layer. :)

Comment: I agree, it's not pretty. Sometimes, however, I'm willing to break the MVC pattern in the interest of getting something done.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in CakePHP 2.x in the security component that allows you to choose to either use the same security token till it expires or just once.
Place this in your controllers beforeFilter method:

```
$this->Security->csrfUseOnce = true;
```

Find more information [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html)

Answer (score 2):

@DoctorFox has already answered it with `csrfUseOnce = true`, but this will throw you in blackholes that you still have to manage. So the complete solution for me is :

```
class YourAppController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components = array('Security');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Security->csrfUseOnce = true;
        $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'blackhole';
    } 

    public function blackhole($type) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```

If there is no redirection, you are still open for double form submission.

Ref : [CakePHP security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just do [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)..It's very simple right?!  Well, at least that's what everyone says but no one posts a clear answer! It took me a week of search and digging and then the "Newbie" decided to do something on his own! Here is one way to do it in cakephp (I use 2.0.5):

Regardless of code here is the logic in steps:
1- set data
2- validate (do NOT create() yet)
3- write $this->request->data to a session variable
4- redirect to a saveData action

Inside saveData action:
5- read & save the session's variable
6- DELETE session's variable
7- create()
8- save data to model
9- redirect

Here is an example of how your code might look like.
**Attn: "**ourController**" and "**ourModel**"

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if (isset($this->request->data)) {
                $this->ourModel->set($this->request->data);
                if ($this->ourModel->validates()) {
                    $this->Session->write('myData', $this->request->data);
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'ourController', 
                                           'action' => 'saveData',
                                           'ourModel' //optional but recommended
                                          )
                                    );
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('ourModel could not be saved.');
                     }
          }
.....//the rest of add() function
}
```

Then you should be redirected (on validation) to this function that redirects you again to index action or wherever your logic takes you!

```
public function saveData($model) {
        $myData = $this->Session->read('myData');
        $this->Session->delete('myData'); //extremely important
        $this->$model->create();
        if ($this->$model->save($myData)) 
               // or $myData[$model] if you are dealing with multiple models
              {
              $this->Session->setFlash(__($model.' have been saved successfully'));
              $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'ourController',
                                    'action' => 'index'
                                    )
                               );
            } 
        } else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__($model.' could not be saved'));
        }
        }
    }
```

A simple self-redirect might work but in most cases you want to redirect to a different view (e.g. to another form or to index view)

I hope this elaboration helps save time on others so not to have to waste a whole week (as in my case) just to do such functionality server-side!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about cake, but try to not display content on a POST request, do a self redirect. The double post will get solved.

Comment: Not particularly helpful -- cake is setup generally to have forms post back to themselves.  Best to continue this, too, because you get lots of stuff (like automatically populating fields on a validation error) with that.

Answer (score 0):

The Security component should work, furthermore, you can also unset the data just after the post:

```
unset($this->data['yourModel']);
```