# How to prevent multiple form submission in CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, duplicates, csrf, cakephp-3.0

I just browsed through this question

> [How to prevent double / duplicate form submissions in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651644/how-to-prevent-double-duplicate-form-submissions-in-cakephp)

But none of the solutions seem to work on CakePHP 3.x.

Like for example, `$this->Security->csrfUseOnce = true;` doesn't help and still duplicate data is accepted.

Has this evolved with the new version of cake? how should I do it in cake 3.0 ?

Comment: What isn't working about the PRG pattern? What are the exact scenarios in which you need duplicate form submission protection?

Comment: @ndm, I just want to prevent user hitting Submit more than once. Of course that can be done using javascript. But for added security, I thought I would validate at the server too because cake's inbuilt Security component makes use of tokens and session variables.

Answer (score 0):

One time tokens were removed from the 3.x CSRF component, as generally session tokens are less hassle. If you want to have single-use tokens you'd need to implement that yourself as a Component in your application/plugin. If you do go down that route, try and use an a datastore that supports atomic get/delete like redis or memcache.